# Google Sheets Javascript - count consecutive negative numbers

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a custom script to count the number of consecutive negative values in an array of data.

I am getting the following error on line 6. How do I loop over a column of data?

"TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."

```
function MaxNegSequence(data) {

  var lCounter = 0;
  var lMaxCount = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < data[i][0].length; i++) {

    if (data[i][0] < 0) {
    lCounter++;
    if (lCounter > lMaxCount) {
      lMaxCount = lCounter;
    }
    else {
      lCounter = 0;
    }
  }
}

return lMaxCount;
```

}

Comment: "Cannot read property "0" from undefined" means that data[i] for some i is undefined. May be an edge case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cannot read property "0" from undefined" means data[i] for some i is undefined. Originally I thought it might be an edge case, but then I saw that you were using an index for `data[j][i]`, instead of just iterating over `data[i]` so you will get extra indices. Change this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[i][0].length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

This will let you iterate over the data. If you need to go piece by piece, then set up a nested for loop instead.